# Local Path Alias for Network Path- Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking

I am using a proprietary program that is looking for a local folder that contains a collection of technical documents (i.e. c:\program files\techpubs\local\airplane\data\AMM_1844). The problem comes because I have the collection of documents installed to a network location (i.e. v:\techpubs\network\airplane\data\AMM_1844). Is there some way to create an alias for the local folder that points to the network folder? For instance, if one were navigate to the local folder on the c: drive they would see the data stored in the v: drive's folder. In essence, I'm trying to trick the program into thinking it is seeing the technical documents, even though they really still live on the file server.

For more background, the technical documents are installed on a network folder, because they are updated frequently and it is unfeasible to update every computer that they would need to be installed locally on.... hopefully I didn't just muddy the water more...

Comment: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-take-advantage-of-symbolic-links-in-window-10/